# How to curl a post request with a bash array?

Tags: bash, curl, post, slack

So I am trying to create a script that will send data to a slack hook app. This is my current code:

```
DATA="[app_code: app_code | error invalid _id: alsdjasdlkj];[app_code: app_code | error invalid _type: 1a1]"

IFS=';' ;read -ra errors <<< "$DATA"
unset IFS

cmd=$(curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "'"${errors[@]}"'" }' hook_url)

echo $cmd
```

The issue I am having is that I want to send an array list of errors as I will never know how many there could be at any given time. when I run this bash command this is the error I get:

```
curl: (3) bad range in URL position 2:
[app_code: app_code | error invalid _type: 1a1]" }
```

So how can I fix the code to send an array as a curl command for the data field? And if that's not possible is there a workaround for this? I need the text to show up on the slack channel as follows:

Total errors: 2
[app_code: app_code | error invalid _id: alsdjasdlkj]
[app_code: app_code | error invalid _type: 1a1]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check you code at https://shellcheck.net . Be sure to include something like `#!/bin/bash` as your first line. If that doesn't solve it, update your Q with the changes suggested. If it does fix it, please delete your Q as it won't be help to future readers here. Good ludk

Comment: Can you show the exact JSON payload you're trying to generate?

Comment: @shellter the shellcheck doesn't show me where to fix the functionality. It suggested to add a * to ${errors[@]} to make it: $*{errors[@]}. However, this makes it output the literal text errors[@] which I do not want.

Comment: @BenjaminW. The payload I am trying to post:

[app_code: app_code | error invalid _id: alsdjasdlkj] [app_code: app_code | error invalid _type: 1a1]

Comment: I thnik you should use `${errors[*]}` instead of `${errors[@]}` And there should be no double quotes in error messages.